# Find equation of a straight line

Tags: geometry

I have the question: Find in the form $ax+by+c=0$, where $a, b$ and $c$ are integers, the equation of the straight line which passes through each pair of points, given by  $(3,0)$ and $(5,2)$

I have worked this out up to $y = x - 3$ , but I am unsure as to whether the final answer should be $x-y-3=0$ by bringing the $y$ to the other side or whether it should be $y-x+3=0$.

Comment: From the question, it looks like $x-y-3=0$ or the "general form" would be best.

Comment: Both forms are fine.

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Yes, the question is posed as "Find in the form ax+by+c=0..."

Comment: So could you leave it as either one or would it be best to leave it as X-Y-3=0 since it is asking for it to be in the form ax+by+c=0?

Comment: Since the question specifically asks you to write it in that form, that is the form you should you. If it didn't say which form to use, then either would be fine.

Comment: Okay, I understand now thanks.

Comment: Why did the question get marked down ? Was it not a suitable question ?

Comment: If the question wants the linear equation to be in the form $ax+by+c=0$, then you write it in that form. But just note that $ax+by+c=0$ isn't a commonly used form.

Comment: @Dan: I don't think there's anything wrong with the question, but sometimes people downvote because they feel the question isn't worthwhile, mathematically (or something).  Please don't let that worry you.

Comment: @Frank: I strongly disagree with an unqualified “$ax+by+c=0$ isn't a commonly used form”: in my field (projective geometry) this and its vector shorthand $(a,b,c)$ are the prevalent ways to describe a line in the plane. And for good reason, e.g. because these avoid the nasty special cases of infinite slope you tend to get for slope-and-intercept parametrizations, or the slightly more difficult transformations you'd get with $ax+by=-c$.

Comment: @MvG In my defense, I haven't gotten to projective geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unsure as to whether the final answer should be $x-y-3=0$ by bringing the $y$ to the other side or whether it should be $y-x+3=0$.

Either solution is correct. If you want to follow the given form more to the letter, you might write your second alternative as $(-1)x+1y+3=0$ to preserve the order of coefficients. The first form would be more explicit as $1x+(-1)y+(-3)=0$, too, but I doubt anyone would actually have trouble reading these coefficients from either of your equations.

The parametrization of the line as you gave it is *homogeneous*, since scaling the equation by any non-zero factor describes the same object. So both the equations above describe the same line, and the equation $3x-3y-9=0$ would still describe the same line.

Formally one could consider $(a,b,c)$ as a coordinate vector, and then consider equivalence classes of all the non-zero multiples of such a vector. The result would be projective space, where each line is represented by homogeneous coordinates. These coordinates are also often written as $[a:b:c]$, with the square brackets indicating (to some) that these are in fact equivalence classes, and with the colons indicating (to some) that the absolute values are irrelevant, it's the ratios between them which describe the object.